# How to write regex pattern for the following string to be matched

Tags: regex, go

I user golang `func (*Regexp) Match` to check if a string matches some pattern.

`matched = regexp.Match(mystr, []byte(pattern))`

How can I write pattern to get `matched=true` when passing mystr fulfilling the following requirements:

- contain at least one "/"
- not start with "alex/", "merry/", "david/"

so mystr="publicfile", "alex/personalfile", "merry/personalfile", "david/personalfile" will get rejected, which means matched=false.

How can I write one patter for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `^(?!alex|merry|david).*\/.*`

Comment: Which regex engine/language: lookahead assertions (as @AvinashRaj used) are very dependent on the regex dialect.

Comment: It is written it is Go. No support for look-arounds :( What about reversing the conditions? If the string has no `/` or starts with the unwanted words? Please check https://ideone.com/wZvvBk

Comment: `match, _ := regexp.MatchString("^(alex|merry|david)|^[^/]+$", "publicfile")
    fmt.Println(match)` here I still get match=true.

Comment: Erm, because it matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach: I reverse the requirements and obtain either `false` or `true`:

```
^(alex|merry|david)|^[^/]+$
```

The regex will match all strings starting with `alex`, `merry` or `david` OR all strings that do not contain `/`, and with `!` operator we reverse the `Match` result:

```
var mystr = "alex/personalfile"
var pattern = regexp.MustCompile(`^(alex|merry|david)|^[^/]+$`) 
var matched = !pattern.Match([]byte(mystr))
fmt.Println(matched)
```

Result: `false`

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/LZiFOB)

Comment: If it does not work, please post the code you have, I will try to adjust it.

Comment: It's working. A great way to go. But I wanted to try to avoid reverse operation. Only lookahead can do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other means to negate something, only a negative look-around. Regex is meant to match something, not to *fail to match* something. In order to fail the match, there are other language-specific features, and one of them is surely `!Match(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:alex|merry|david).*|(.*\/.*))$
```

You can try something like this.This will match all but you need to grab the `groups` only.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/27